# how to compare a current row with all previous rows in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r

```
  No.   value      time
  1       2         12  
  2       4         23
  3       6         13
  4       8         8
  5       10        13
  6       12        24
```

My desired dataframe is

```
 No.    value      time     flag
  1       2         12      0   NA
  2       4         23      0  (4 >= 12)
  3       6         13      0  (6 >= 23,12) 
  4       8         8       0  (8 >= 13,23,12)
  5       10        13      1  (10 >= 8,13,23,12) Satisfied
  6       12        24      1  (12 >= 13,23,12) Satisfied 
  7       14        23      1
```

I want to check if current value is greater than or equal to all previous rows of time column  and if the condition satisfies it will set the flag to 1.

```
 df$flag <- ifelse(df$value >= lag(df$time),1,0)
```

But,this gives me last value to compare not all n previous rows. 
how can i do it in r ?

Comment: 10 compared with all previous rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.numeric(c(FALSE, sapply(2:length(df$value), function(i)
    any(df$value[i] >= df$time[1:(i-1)]))))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(No. = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), value = c(2, 4, 
6, 8, 10, 12, 14), time = c(12, 23, 13, 8, 13, 24, 23)), .Names = c("No.", 
"value", "time"), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.works perfectly. can we do something like once the value is taken for comparison for the next time that value is omitted and rest values are compared ?

Answer (score 2):

Your output doesn't make sense, as in my book 10 is still smaller than 23. But for the sake of the argument, let's take these to vectors:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- seq(2,20, by = 2)
y <- sample(4:13)
```

Then you can easily do what you want using `cummax` like this:

```
x >= cummax(y)
```

The outcome:

```
> x >= cummax(y)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

> x
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20

> y
 [1]  7  6  8  4 12  9 13  5 11 10
```

EDIT: After realizing you asked something completely different to what you actually want, this soludion of d.b would be the solution to get what you need:

```
c(NA, x[-1] >= cummin(head(y, -1)))
#  [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I think for this one, `c(FALSE, df$value[-1] >= cummin(head(df$time, -1)))` might be what's needed