# Compare all rows to current in R grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to determine if there are any rows within a group that have a Version that is exactly 1 less than any other row for the group and label it in another column. I have looked at lag and lead but the problem is that the rows that are 1 different in value may or may not be adjacent to each other.

Here is a reproducible example

**Data:**

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble('Plate' = c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3","A3"),
             'Sample' = c("a", "a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b","b","a","b","b","c","c","c"),
             'Location' = c("x","x","x","y","y","y","y","x","x","x","x","y","y","x","x","x"),
             'Version' = c(1,1.2,2,22,26,9,9.3,11,11.3,12,19,32.2,33.2,14,15,15))
```

**Last iteration of what I have tried**
Adapted from [how to compare a current row with all previous rows in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119714/how-to-compare-a-current-row-with-all-previous-rows-in-r)
(and others)

```
df_test <- df  %>%
  group_by(Plate,Sample,Location) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Version)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = sapply(seq_along(Version), function(i){
    if_else(any(.[1:(i-1),'Version'] - .[[i,'Version']] == 1.0), -1.0, 0)})
    )
```

**Expected output:**

```
   Plate Sample Location Version  diff
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A3    b      y           33.2     0
 2 A3    b      y           32.2    -1
 3 A1    b      y           26       0
 4 A1    b      y           22       0
 5 A3    a      x           19       0
 6 A3    c      x           15       0
 7 A3    c      x           15       0
 8 A3    c      x           14      -1
 9 A2    b      x           12       0
10 A2    b      x           11.3     0
11 A2    b      x           11      -1
12 A2    a      y            9.3     0
13 A2    a      y            9       0
14 A1    a      x            2       0
15 A1    a      x            1.2     0
16 A1    a      x            1      -1
```

**Actual Output:**

```
   Plate Sample Location Version  diff
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A3    b      y           33.2     0
 2 A3    b      y           32.2    -1
 3 A1    b      y           26       0
 4 A1    b      y           22      -1
 5 A3    a      x           19       0
 6 A3    c      x           15       0
 7 A3    c      x           15      -1
 8 A3    c      x           14       0
 9 A2    b      x           12       0
10 A2    b      x           11.3    -1
11 A2    b      x           11       0
12 A2    a      y            9.3     0
13 A2    a      y            9      -1
14 A1    a      x            2       0
15 A1    a      x            1.2    -1
16 A1    a      x            1       0
```

It appears that is is looking at row index for the comparison (or ignoring the groups?), how do I get it to look at value?  It feels like I am close.  I would prefer a dplyr answer but data.table acceptable if I need to. Sorry if I have missed an already answered relevant post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
df  %>%
  group_by(Plate,Sample,Location) %>%
  mutate(diff = if_else((Version + 1) %in% Version, -1, 0))
# # A tibble: 16 x 5
# # Groups:   Plate, Sample, Location [7]
#    Plate Sample Location Version  diff
#    <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A1    a      x            1      -1
#  2 A1    a      x            1.2     0
#  3 A1    a      x            2       0
#  4 A1    b      y           22       0
#  5 A1    b      y           26       0
#  6 A2    a      y            9       0
#  7 A2    a      y            9.3     0
#  8 A2    b      x           11      -1
#  9 A2    b      x           11.3     0
# 10 A2    b      x           12       0
# 11 A3    a      x           19       0
# 12 A3    b      y           32.2    -1
# 13 A3    b      y           33.2     0
# 14 A3    c      x           14      -1
# 15 A3    c      x           15       0
# 16 A3    c      x           15       0
```

There is a bit of a risk of numerical precision issues, since your versions aren't all integers, but it seems to work for your example where the numbers are relatively low.

A numerically stable version might look like this:

```
df  %>%
  group_by(Plate,Sample,Location) %>%
  mutate(diff = if_else(apply(abs(outer(Version, Version, "-") + 1) < 1e-10, 1, any), -1, 0))
```

(for the same result as above)

To understand how/why it works, start with a text vector like `x = c(1, 1.2, 2)` and run pieces of code on it - `outer(x, x, "-")`, then add in the `+ 1`, etc.

Comment: Awesome thanks Gregor! That worked perfectly and definitely tidier than what I was working towards